# Databricks Delta Live Table - How To Simply Append A Batch Source To a DLT Table?

Tags: pyspark, databricks, delta-live-tables

Using Python and all the relevant DLT properties within Databricks, does anyone know how to simple append to a DLT table from a batch source?

In PySpark you can just use df.write.format("delta").mode("append") but since dlt requires you to return a Spark dataframe within its decorator, we can't use the Dataframe Writer API.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delta Live Tables has a notion of a *[streaming live table](https://docs.databricks.com/data-engineering/delta-live-tables/delta-live-tables-concepts.html#datasets)* that is append-only by default. You can define your pipeline as [triggered](https://docs.databricks.com/data-engineering/delta-live-tables/delta-live-tables-concepts.html#continuous-and-triggered-pipelines), that will be equivalent of the the `Trigger.Once`.  Something like that:

```
@dlt.table
def append_only():
  return spark.readStream.format("xyz").load()
```

Here we use `readStream` just to make sure that when we run the pipeline again we won't append the same content again & again.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex! Appreciate the clarification, cheers.

Comment: Hi Alex, hope you don't mind this follow up: For this DLT streaming table using spark.readStream, is it possible to pass in an array of sources that have the same schema but found in different timestamp folders? I tested the following pseudo code but it didn't work so was wondering if you have any tips please? Thanks in advance.

`code`
@dlt.table(
    name=silver_table,
    path=f"abfss://{TargetContainer}@{StorageAccountName}.dfs.core.windows.net/{TargetDirectory}"
)
def silver_table():
    for each_row in array:
        df = spark.readStream………(each_row)
        return df
`code`

Comment: you can use glob pattern to specify multiple folders under the same location... Otherwise it's either readStream for each folder & union with others (it may break if you add or remove sources), or use this recipe to programmatically create individual nodes in the DLT graph for each of locations; https://docs.databricks.com/data-engineering/delta-live-tables/delta-live-tables-cookbook.html#programmatically-manage-and-create-multiple-live-tables

Comment: Thanks once again Alex; I will stick to my current glob pattern then. Cheers.

Comment: Within this solution, what happens if what we appended to the target table in the first run is not available in the source at the second run. Will this create issues?

Comment: it depends on the source...

Comment: Hello, a quick question on this solution, based on the Databricks documentation, if there are non-append operations at the source, the source table becomes unstreamable. Using the ignoreDeletes or skipChangeCommits flags might lead to incorrect data, since deleted or updated records at the source won't be taken into account. How can we mitigate this issue?

Comment: You can enable change data feed on the source table, and then consume changes.  But take into account that it's possible only at the first level of the DLT - when you use `spark.readStream`. If it's later in the pipeline, then you need to use `LIVE TABLE`, not streaming table, and DLT will try to optimize recalculations